# Is it insecure to use a swap file that multiple systems can read?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, security, storage

I'm setting up a dual-boot system with Ubuntu Linux and Windows 7. Both systems are installed on an SSD, each given around 50GB. However, there is an additional internal HDD with a single `ext4` partition, which I plan to use both form Ubuntu and from Windows.

I also want to give Ubuntu swap space, but I don't want to waste precious SSD storage for that (I will only use it rarely I think). My solution was to create a swap file on the internal drive, but that got me thinking about security.

**If both systems can read the swap file, and Windows can ignore the permissions I set on it, is it possible that some important data like passwords could be read by malicious Windows programs?** And what can I do about that? (Once I install `ext4` drivers on Windows, it will probably be able to read from my SSD swap file if I were to put it there, as well.)

Comment: At best, it would probably only store a password hash. Passwords are not stored in long-term memory as a general rule... they might be used for authentication within the context of a function in a program, but after that function returns there is no reason to store the password in memory any longer. Applications that *do* hold onto passwords usually do so by hashing the user's input string into something unrecognizable by a human but still usable for challenge-response authentication. I would be more concerned about other points of privacy data that are not handled so gingerly.

Comment: Windows can read ext4 filesystems now?

Comment: @Majenko No, but aren't there ways to directly access the device? If so, couldn't a userspace implementation in the malware suffice? Also, you can actually install drivers for ext4, which is what I *was* doing, until I realize that the quality of those drivers was suboptimal and the user experience was not transparent (the program always had to reside in the userspace actually). Some implementations even had glaring feature omissions such as no write support or were unsafe and experimental.

Comment: Now I just use a shared NTFS partition, without reading ext4 from Windows.

Comment: I can't believe anyone would spend the time and effort to write Windows malware that would read raw data from an ext4 partition, find a swapfile on it, and work out what in it is sensitive information. The ROI would be zero.

Comment: I agree, and there are more logical attack vectors when you have such access from another OS, but it was interesting and I learned something :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that sensitive information could be written to the swap file/partition, and it would then be readable from another operating system.

These resources will help you protect that information:

- If you are using a swap **file**: [Q: How do I setup an encrypted swap file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/248558/61970)
- If you are using a swap **partition** [Encrypting your Ubuntu swap partition](http://iwtf.net/2010/01/05/encrypting-your-ubuntu-swap-partition/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk indeed, but it's low. I don't think there's much Windows malware reading remaining bits from Linux swapping.

Also security conscious Linux programs can tell the kernel to keep some bits of information only in RAM and not to swap them. There aren't guarantees that the kernel will respect the request, but at least it will try. For more details read the [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) man page.